# awscli filter aws describe-auto-scaling-groups by multiple tag values

Tags: tags, aws-cli, jmespath

I have attempted and failed so far to achieve the below,

Tags = 1
Values = Multiple (minimum 3) otherwise I could use OR as per example below,

```
aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --query 'AutoScalingGroups[?contains(Tags[?Key==`marco`].Value,`polo`) || contains(Tags[?Key==`marco`].Value,`bolo`)].[AutoScalingGroupName]'
```

I've attempted to use https://jmespath.org/proposals/functions.html#contains

Either my syntax is off or the matching criteria isn't correct i.e. won't match against partial values or upper/lower case matters.

The below does not error out but it returns no matches.

```
aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --query 'AutoScalingGroups[?contains(Tags[?Key==`Marco`].Value, [`polo`, `bolo`, `rolo`])].[AutoScalingGroupName]'
```

Reference

```
        "Tags": [
            {
                "ResourceId": "MyASG",
                "ResourceType": "auto-scaling-group",
                "Key": "marco",
                "Value": "polo",
                "PropagateAtLaunch": true
            }
```

Goal: There are a large number of ASG and I wish to return the AutoScalingGroupName which will be fed to another step.

Answer (score 1):

With some help and fiddling I ended up with a working result.

```
aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --query 'AutoScalingGroups[?contains([`Value1`, `Value2`, `Value3`], Tags[?Key==`Keyname`].Value[] | [0])].[AutoScalingGroupName]'
```